# Execute procedure strored in Oracle from MySQL server (mairadb)

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have to execute on demand procedure.

When somene logs in to presta shop, i need to generete and insert prices for thatn user.

Prices are in ERP in Oracle, i use ERP native function to calculate price for user X, and i can insert  that infrmation directly to Mysql DB @dbling.

The last thing i need to do is execute from mysql procedure stroed in oracle, something. Execution will be initiated by prestashop when somend logs in.

**EXAMPLE PSEUDO CODE:**

```
 begin 
      price_proc@oracle(hopid,clintID));
    end;
```

I'cant find it in doc.

Comment: I wouldn't know, I don't use MySQL. But, code you posted has **one** opening and **two** closing brackets. Could that be a culprit?

Comment: That's an typo, only a typo. That's not a real code, just a example how it's done in oracle between db/instances. I can't find instruction how to construct analog of that in MySQL ---> oracle.

Comment: Neither mysql, nor mariadb can execute stored procedures in another rdbms product. You are probably better off implementing this feature in the application code - e.g. PrestaShop code can connect to Oracle, execute the function#, get the returned value and save it to mariadb. Btw, mariadb and mysql are **not** the same.

Comment: I was afraid of this, thanks for the answer, I will not waste any more time on this solution. I will connect PHP to Oracle and achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible - according to @Shadow i a comment above.

It's possible other way around, it is possible to execute procedure in MariaDB from Oracle.

Example

@www it the DB link for MariaDB

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure B2C_REFRENCE_UPDATE (pNRZM VARCHAR2) IS
  dummy CHAR;
BEGIN
  dummy := DBMS_HS_PASSTHROUGH.EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE@www
  (
       'CALL `B2C_REFRENCE_UPDATE`('''||pNRZM||''');'
  );
END;
```